# How do I send messages from my swift file to Unity (NOT from Unity to swift)

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine

I have been having the hardest time watching tutorials and reading documentation on how to bridge Unity and Swift together. It seems most people are looking for a way to have Unity send messages to the swift file. I am looking for the exact opposite. I would like to specifically send screenshot detection messages back to my Unity project.

So far, I have tried using the NotificationCenter.addObserver methods.

Combined with the built-in "UnitySendMessage" function (in the XCode main.mm file) I was expecting it to update my Unity project with no problem.

Is there anybody else that has achieved this?